# How to redo makemigrations after getting an error?

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-1.9

So first I ran `makemigrations` and then I ran `migrate` and got the error `ValueError: The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.`

So I went ahead, modified my `models.py` to fix that error.

Now, when I run `makemigrations` to start over again, it works. Then `migrate` didn't actually do anything but show the error again. So there is a migration there that is bad, then there is one after that is proper.

So I tried running `./manage.py migrate --fake mainapp zero` after reading it on Stack Overflow and now it's saying `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'mainapp_article' already exists")`.

Any ideas how I can get back to where I started, and retry the makemigrations now with the error removed from models.py?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Identify your last success migration:

```
./manage.py showmigrations mainapp
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_auto_20160425_0102
[X] 0003_auto_20160426_2022
[X] 0004_auto_20160427_0036
```

2) Then use migrate to migrate your database to that specified migration point.

```
 ./manage.py migrate mainapp 0003_auto_20160426_2022
```

In this example I'm assuming the 0003 migration was success while the 0004 wasn't.

3) Remove the migration file

```
rm mainapp/migrations/0004_auto_20160427_0036.py*
```

4) Run makemigrations and migrate again.

Comment: Ouch... `showmigrations` option was introduced in django 1.8. https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-showmigrations

Comment: I just jumped to Django 1.9. I'll update the question. Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have bad migration, you should simply remove it and generate it again.